# How can I center the head of a table in LateX?

Tags: latex, positioning, centering

I obtain this:

[image]

I cannot figure out how can I center the first column name vertically.
Below is my current code:

```
\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage\[utf8\]{inputenc}
\\usepackage{longtable}
\\usepackage{multirow}
\\usepackage{array}
\\title{teste}
\\begin{document}
\\setlength{\\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\\renewcommand{\\arraystretch}{1.1}
\\newcolumntype{M}\[1\]{\>{\\centering\\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\\begin{longtable}
{|M{2,5cm}||M{1,3cm}|M{2,1cm}|M{3,1cm}|M{2,4cm}| }
\\hline
\\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{MODELS} \\
\\hline
\\vspace{1.9cm}
Nome& Tipo &Estimativa de Custo Anual&Requisitos Cumpridos& Último Update\\
\\hline
\\endhead
ABC   & C& 9.999&Sim &Não\\
\\hline
\\end{longtable}
\\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post your example code with out all the duplicate \\ and the escaped []?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please always provide a minimum working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)). This is code we can compile and test. You should also clean your code before posting. Otherwise, you ask potential contributor for the extra unnecessary work to help you.*

I suggest another long-table related environment `xltabular`. It is similar to `longtable` but accepts the `X` column type, which adapts width to the rest of the table; it's a convenient way to avoid unnecessary calculations to get a proper dimension of your table, which does not exceed page dimensions.

With `X` which uses `p{}` under the hood, you get the correct alignment of the first cell. I also recommend reducing avoiding vertical to a minimum. In your case, I left the one between the first column and "the rest" of the table. I also demonstrated how you could add bars and rules of different thicknesses.

Finally, I added `\endfoot` so the table is correctly closed on subsequent pages.

**Note**. On one hand, you are using `,` as a decimal marker in a column definition and `.` in the content of the table. I was surprised the code actually get compiled.

EDIT. I use a `\xmathstrut` macro from `mathtools` to add some vertical spacing in your header. Lower the value from `2` to reduce the spacing.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% \title{teste}


\begin{document}
% --- BEGIN GROUP -------------------------
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{
  X !{\vrule width 0.2pt}
  M{1,3cm}
  M{2,1cm}
  M{3,1cm}
  M{2,4cm}
}
  \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{MODELS} \\
  \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
  $\xmathstrut{2}$Nome
  & Tipo
  & Estimativa de Custo Anual
  & Requisitos Cumpridos
  & Último Update \\
  \noalign{\hrule height 0.5pt} \endhead
  \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt} \endfoot
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
  ABC & C & 9.999 & Sim & Não\\
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
% --- END GROUP ---------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]